# AFNetworking issue: NSErrorFailingURLKey=url, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I am calling POST and sending nested JSON to the server as follows:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"user":@{@"accountId":@0,@"active":@NO,@"createdBy":@0,@"createdOn":@"", @"emailAddress":@"", @"firstName":@"", @"gender":@0, @"id":@9, @"lastName":@"", @"role":@5,},@"punchInLocation": @"",
                           @"punchInLatitude": @18.5081214,
                           @"punchInLangitude": @73.8431377,
                           @"punchOutLocation": @"",
                           @"punchOutLatitude":@0,
                           @"punchOutLagitude": @0,
                           @"punchInLocationNotFoundReason": @"NetworkProblem",
                           @"punchOutLocationNotFoundReason": @"",
                           @"sdate": @"2014-12-10",
                           @"spunchInTime": @"08:37:44"
                           };

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"<<removed>>" forHTTPHeaderField:@"userToken"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager POST:@"<<removed>>" parameters:json success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But I am getting error as below

```
{ status code: 400, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "http://onboard.qlc.in";
"Cache-Control" = public;
Connection = close;
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 393;
"Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 18 May 2015 09:24:50 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.40";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
} 
}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=url, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did the issue resolved??

Answer (score 1):

"punchOutLagitude" and "punchInLangitude" have a typo in them

They should be "punchOutLatitude" and "punchInLongitude" respectively